# name '_C' is not defined pytorch+jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, jupyter

I have some code that uses pytorch, that runs fine from my IDE (pycharm).

For research, I tried to run it from a jupyter notebook.

The code in the notebook:

```
from algorithms import Argparser
from algorithms import Session
def main():
    print("main started")
    args = Argparser.parse()
    session = Session(args)
    session.run()
```

The package looks like:

```
|-algorithms
|---__init__.py
|---Argparser.py
|---Session.py
|---<many more files that are being used by Session>.py
```

some of those files do `import torch`

When running the code in the notebook, I get

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 from algorithms import Argparser
>   ----> 2 from algorithms import Session
>         3 def main():
>         4     print("main started")
>         5     args = Argparser.parse()
>
> D:\git\stav\stav-rl\algorithms\Session.py in 
>        12 
>        13 
>   ---> 14 from algorithms.Episode import Episode
>        15 from algorithms.Agent import Agent
>        16 import torch
>
> D:\git\stav\stav-rl\algorithms\Episode.py in 
>         1 **author** = 'Noam'
>         2 
>   ----> 3 import torch
>         4 import numpy as np
>         5 import cv2
>
> c:\anaconda3\envs\threadartrl\lib\site-packages\torch__init__.py in
>   
>        84 from torch._C import *
>        85 
>   ---> 86 **all** += [name for name in dir(*C)
>        87             if name[0] != '*' and
>        88             not name.endswith('Base')]
>
> NameError: name '_C' is not defined

The error is on `from algorithms import Session-->...-->import torch`

How can i get the code to run?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need Cython for pytorch to work:

```
pip3 install Cython
```

See [this comment on the issue on github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1633#issuecomment-418237093).

My understanding is that there is a library called `_C.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` in `site-packages/torch` which provides the shared object `_C` and requires Cython. PyCharm provides Cython support whereas the Jupyter environment doesn't.

Comment: just found it myself and was about to post, thanks!
but WHY dos that solve the problem?

Comment: I think it's because some library uses Cython. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, these error messages were not helpful!  Additionally, like @Sankha Jayalath said, restart your kernel after.

Answer (score 50):

Restarting the kernel will solve the problem.

Comment: turn it off and on... how could I forget?

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Try Jacques Gaudin's solution then restart.

Answer (score 1):

I was not using a notebook, so maybe this is a different issue, but I recently got the same error after upgrading my system libffi. I was able to fix this by installing libffi7.

I went ahead and [made a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70107055/nameerror-name-c-is-not-defined/70107072#70107072) on the assumption this is a different issue, but figured I'd post here in case.

Answer (score 0):

After running `pip3 install Cython`, I still got this error,

but I recalled the first error hints: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy',

so I tried this:  `pip3 install sympy`, it worked!

Answer (score -1):

in my case (google colab), i restarted my runtime and it works.

Runtime > Restart runtime

Answer (score -1):

You probably interrupted the program at line :

```py
import torch
```

Restarting the runtime shall fix the issue. If you for some reason don't want to restart the kernel, try to reinstall and reimport pytorch