# Problem with Installing and Running PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I tried to use Anaconda to install PyTorch. I used

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch
```

Then I use

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch
```

When I run

```
import torch
```

I get the following error

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import torch

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch__init__.py in

84 from torch._C import *

85

---> 86 **all** += [name for name in dir(_C)

87             if name[0] != '_' and

88             not name.endswith('Base')]

NameError: name '_C' is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [name '\_C' is not defined pytorch+jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408973/name-c-is-not-defined-pytorchjupyter-notebook)

Comment: Why don't you follow the official instructions [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)?

Comment: I tried to install Cython and It is shown that "Requirement already satisfied: Cython in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages" but the "name '_C' is not defined" is still there