# torch NameError: name '_C' is not defined

Tags: ubuntu, pytorch, jupyter, cython

I'm getting the following error when trying to `import torch` in Jupyter:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-39178> in <module>
      1 
----> 2 import torch

~/jupyter_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py in <module>
     84 from torch._C import *
     85 
---> 86 __all__ += [name for name in dir(_C)
     87             if name[0] != '_' and
     88             not name.endswith('Base')]

NameError: name '_C' is not defined


     88             not name.endswith('Base')]

NameError: name '_C' is not defined
```

`Cython` is already installed, in case you may be wondering.

Any idea how to fix this?

---

UPDATE:

Three years later, I'm getting the same error when attempting to `import torch` in Python 3.8.0!

running it from an empty dir makes it go passed this issue.
i.e. try the following

`mkdir empty_dir && cd empty_dir && python -c 'import torch'`

source: [answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nameerror-name-c-is-not-defined-while-importing-torch/124721)

Also, I just wan to put it out there that the root cause of this issue **for me** when importing torch was a broken numpy installation. The thing that ended up solving the entirety of the issue was a simple `pip install numpy==1.23.2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [name '\_C' is not defined pytorch+jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408973/name-c-is-not-defined-pytorchjupyter-notebook)

Comment: @polm23 Nope! :-/

Comment: useful source: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nameerror-name-c-is-not-defined-while-importing-torch/124721