# Colab SpaCy | PyTorch NameError: name '_C' is not defined

Tags: google-colaboratory, spacy, torch

Trying to import spacy into Google Colab but getting an error `name '_C' is not defined`. Is it problem with the torch somewhere inside? [image: screen with the error]

torch version: 1.13.1
spacy version: 3.5.0

I've tried to upgrade spacy and cython, but it didn't work. What should I do?

As I said I've tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70107055/nameerror-name-c-is-not-defined/70107072#70107072), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408973/name-c-is-not-defined-pytorchjupyter-notebook) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679961/torch-nameerror-name-c-is-not-defined)

When I'm trying to downgrade numpy I'm getting a dependency error with scipy.
I've also tried to install torch 1.9.0 as in [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nameerror-name-c-is-not-defined-while-importing-torch/124721/3) but it also didn't work.
And I've tried to downgrade to spacy 3.4.3 which runs perfectly on my local machine -- didn't work.

**UPD:** just discovered that importing torch shows same error

**UPD_2:** this happened when I've uploaded my own notebook. When I open a new clear notebook -- everything works just fine.